# A smart algorithm to decide whether a simple graph is 2-regular

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a simple graph $(V,E)$, is there a smart algorithm to decide if the graph is 2-regular? Is it really necessary to check that all nodes in the graph appears exactly twice?

I have implemented nested sets and enjoy myself defining algorithms, for example for simple graphs. What strikes me is that straight forward algorithms to check "trivial" properties (connectedness, trees, 2-regularity etc) become so tedious — and unefficient.

Comment: By generated do you mean induced?

Comment: @Shahab, yes I will edit.

Comment: What do you mean by cyclic? Do you mean if every vertex on each component belongs to a cycle? Or if each component has a cycle?

Comment: @ml0105. A cyclic graph is a closed chain of edges where each vertex is common to exact two edges, and a component is an isolated subgraph.

Comment: Will you consider two vertex disjoint triangles as one cyclic graph or two cyclic graphs?

Comment: @Shahab, as a graph with two cyclic components.

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, you are given a graph and want to check whether it is $2$-regular and are looking for an efficient way to do so. Is this correct?

Comment: I personally don't know how to do that very efficiently but I think if you rephrase the question (add the bit about $2$-regular) and add a little context as to why you want to do this you may get a better response.

Comment: @Shahab. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

How are you representing your graph? If you are using an adjacency matrix, then it suffices to check if $A1 = 2$, where $1$ is the vector of all $1$'s and $2$ is the vector of all $2$'s. In other words, $\lambda = 2$ is the largest eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector $1$. Matrix multiplication takes quadratic time though.

If you are using an adjacency or incidence list representation, it suffices to check if each vertex has precisely two neighbors. This takes constant time for a given vertex and $O(V)$ time for the graph.

Nested sets doesn't seem like a good approach to model your graph. When working with graphs, your method for representing them should be tailored to what you are doing. Certain representations are better for certain applications.

Comment: I represent a simple graph as a pair $(V,E)$ where $E$ is a set of unordered pairs of $V$. No it doesn't seems to be efficient, but my purpose is to enjoy implementing mathematical structures with my set implementation.

Comment: With that representation, I'd iterate through the edges. For each endpoint, increment its count. A hash table is a good data structure for this. If you find a vertex with count more than $2$, return false. At the end, it suffices to validate that each vertex is in the hash table and has count $2$. This is an $O(V + E)$ time algorithm.